# Continuous functions $f$, $g$ from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \left\{0\right\}$ are homotopic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose we have $f$, $g$ continuous mappings from a space $X$ to $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \left\{0\right\}$ with $\|f(x)-g(x)\|\leq \|f(x)\|$, prove that $f$, $g$ are homotopic.

Is anyone willing to help me solve this? I thought about using the straight line homotopy, but I'm not sure it would work.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You’re supposed to use Latex on this site to edit math texts. Also your question is not correct as you’re comparing real values with vectors which doesn’t make sense. Can you please update your question?

Comment: Yes thank you, I will use Latex, sorry 
Also you're right, I wrote it wrong, it's corrected now

Comment: Hint: Use the condition to show that $tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)\neq 0$ for $x\in X$ and $t\in[0,1].$

Comment: Thanks a lot, that actually helped me solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work. Define $F:X\times I\to\mathbb{R^n}\setminus\{0\}$ by $F(x,t)=(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)$. The only thing which is not immediately clear is why $F(x,t)$ is never equal to $0$. Well, if $t=1$ then $F(x,t)=g(x)$ and so it isn't $0$. Now let $t\in [0,1)$. Assume there is some $x\in X$ such that $F(x,t)=0$. Then:

$0=(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)=f(x)-t(f(x)-g(x))$

$f(x)=t(f(x)-g(x))$

By taking norm on both sides we obtain $||f(x)||=t||f(x)-g(x)||\leq t||f(x)||$. Since $t\in [0,1)$ this implies $||f(x)||=0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: THANK YOU, YOU ARE A LIFESAVER